# PL/SQL help. How to write a anonymous block that inserts 100 new rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL (and programming in general) and been set a few tasks. I am working my way through them and getting on OKish but am stumped with this particular task. I using the Oracle Application Express and have created the table that I am working with which is called emp2

Here is the task in it's entirety:
Write a PL/SQL anonymous block that inserts 100 (new) employee IDs,
 starting at number 2000. Use a FOR loop, and declaration block for
 defining the lower/upper limits of the loop. In addition to
 the employee IDs, also add code that inserts placeholders in
 the first_name and last_name columns (avoid NULLs!), eg
 "FName_2000" and "LName_2000" for employee ID 2000.
 (Hint: Use the concatenation operator).

This is the code that I have written so far (which I thought was spot on) minus the VALUES, as I just could not get this part to work?

```
    DECLARE
      lower constant pls_integer := 2000;
      upper constant pls_integer := 2099;
    BEGIN
      FOR i in lower..upper 
       LOOP
          INSERT INTO emp2 ( EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY,              
          DEPARTMENT_ID )
          VALUES ( //UNSURE WHAT GOES HERE!  );
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' row');
      END LOOP;
     END;
```

Comment: When you say you could not get the `VALUES` part to work, have you tried a few things and not got them to work?  If so, please edit your question to include what you've tried and the error messages you received.

Comment: Well what I mean is that this is my first task where I have to use values. I 'know' that values is used here but don't how or what?

Comment: The `VALUES` section of an `INSERT` statement contains a comma-separated list of values to insert into each column.  The first value in the `VALUES` section goes into the first column name in the `INSERT` statement (i.e. `EMPLOYEE_ID`), the second value goes into the `FIRST_NAME` column, and so on.  Can you find values for each of the six columns, or are there any columns you're struggling with?

Comment: That makes sense to me but I though values would look something like (2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000) as the task says 100 (new) employee IDs, starting at number 2000.?? This however does not work? I am just not understanding this bit at all?

Comment: I think the question could be clarified a bit.  It should read "inserts 100 (new) employee records".  For the first employee, the employee ID should be 2000, but the first name should be `FName_2000`, not just 2000.  And when you say this 'does not work', what do you mean?  Does Oracle report an error or does no data get inserted?

Comment: Ok, I tried (2000, "FName_2000", "LName_2000", "HDate_2000", "Date_2000", "Salary_2000") and got this error.  ORA-06550: line 8, column 32:
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


6.   LOOP
7.     INSERT INTO emp2 ( EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID )
8.     VALUES ( 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000 );
9.   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' row');
10.   END LOOP;

Comment: The error message says that you tried to put a number in the `HIRE_DATE` column.  I would imagine that that column wants a `DATE` value instead.  As this only an example task, let's pretend all the employees were all hired the same day, January 1 this year.  Use `TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` for the value for the `HIRE_DATE` column.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help! This is how VALUES looked in the end -  VALUES ( 2000, 'FName_2000', 'LName_2000', '01/Jan/2013', 2000, 2000);  Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Does that mean you've figured out how to (a) insert all 1000 employees, with IDs from 2000 to 2999, (b) insert 1000 employees, all with the same ID 2000, or (c) insert one employee with ID 2000?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. The incrementing ID's was the critical bit and that it was working fine buy using 'i' in the VALUES. code I posted before had 2000 instead of 'i' but I can't edit that post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statement should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO emp2 
( EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID )
VALUES 
( i, 'Fname', 'Lname', sysdate, 100, 10 );
```

You need to add an IF statement for the part "also add code that inserts placeholders in the first_name and last_name columns for employee ID 2000". Like this:

```
IF i = 2000
THEN
   INSERT INTO emp2 
   ( EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID )
   VALUES 
   ( i, 'Fname ' || i, 'Lname ' || i, sysdate, 100, 10 );
ELSE
   INSERT INTO emp2 
   ( EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID )
   VALUES 
   ( i, 'Fname', 'Lname', sysdate, 100, 10 );
END IF;
```

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the question slightly.  I don't see the need for the employee with ID 2000 to be treated differently.

Comment: You may be correct? The way I read "100 (new) employee IDs, starting at number 2000" meant, to me at least, that each record should increment?